# Recursion: Backtracking sudoku solver in JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, sudoku

I can't get this recursive algorithm working. It should solve a sudoku grid (a 2d array of ints). I've made the same in Java (but OOP of course) and it works fine. But in JS it doesn't. Values in the grid doesn't get changed and it never reaches the base case. The algorithm is solveSudoku - the base case is, when it searches through the grid but doesn't find any "empty" cells (with a value of '0').

I've put all the code in one file. Can you spot the error? I've been trying for a week now and about to abandom this little project.

```
"use strict";

var grid = [
        [0,0,8,4,0,3,5,0,6],
        [0,0,3,1,0,2,0,0,4],
        [0,4,5,7,0,0,0,9,0],
        [6,9,0,0,0,5,0,0,7],
        [0,8,0,0,0,0,0,5,0],
        [4,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,8],
        [0,7,0,0,0,6,2,4,0],
        [1,0,0,5,0,7,8,0,0],
        [8,0,6,9,0,1,3,0,0]
    ];

// recursive algo
function solveSudoku(grid, row, col) {
    var cell = findUnassignedLocation(grid, row, col);
    row = cell[0];
    col = cell[1];

    // base case: if no empty cell  
    if (row == -1) {
        console.log("solved");
        return true;
    }

    for (var num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {

        if ( noConflicts(grid, row, col, num) ) {   
            grid[row][col] = num;

            if ( solveSudoku(grid, row, col) ) {                
                return true;
            }

                    // mark cell as empty (with 0)    
            grid[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }

    // trigger back tracking
    return false;
}


function findUnassignedLocation(grid, row, col) {
    var done = false;
    var res = [-1, -1];

    while (!done) {
        if (row == 9) {
            done = true;
        }
        else {
            if (grid[row][col] == 0) {
                res[0] = row;
                res[1] = col;
                done = true;
            }
            else {
                if (col < 8) {
                    col++;
                }
                else {
                    row++;
                    col = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}

function noConflicts(grid, row, col, num) {
    return isRowOk(grid, row, num) && isColOk(grid, col, num) && isBoxOk(grid, row, col, num);
}

function isRowOk(grid, row, num) {
    for (var col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        if (grid[row][col] == num)
            return false;

    return true;
}
function isColOk(grid, col, num) {
    for (var row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    if (grid[row][col] == num)
        return false;

    return true;    
}
function isBoxOk(grid, row, col, num) {
    row = (row / 3) * 3;
    col = (col / 3) * 3;

    for (var r = 0; r < 3; r++)
        for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            if (grid[row + r][col + c] == num)
                return false;

    return true;
}

function printGrid(grid) {
    var res = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            res += grid[i][j];
        }
        res += "\n";
    }
    console.log(res);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: No error msgs. It just prints out the grid unchanged. I'm using Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: The code seems fine. I can only assume this means that your particular Sudoku puzzle can't be solved naively.

Comment: Java can! Could it be that JS recursive abilities is limited in some way, like number of calls to stack is too limited etc..

Comment: The code is **almost** fine, and the puzzle can indeed be solved by it :-)

Comment: In addition to way others have said, the local variable `grid` is shadowing the global `grid`.  I would rename the global to `gGrid`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was tricky to find... but the problem is in

```
row = (row / 3) * 3;
col = (col / 3) * 3;
```

Javascript uses only floating point numbers so this is not doing what you think is doing.

The solution is

```
row = Math.floor(row / 3) * 3;
col = Math.floor(col / 3) * 3;
```

Comment: Ah! Great catch! Not entirely sure how I missed that, considering it's a bit of a no-op with floats XD

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, numbers can't be forced to be integer so something like `(a / 3) * 3` is not different from `a`.
In `isBoxOk`, you need to replace

```
row = (row / 3) * 3;
col = (col / 3) * 3;
```

by

```
row = Math.floor(row / 3) * 3;
col = Math.floor(col / 3) * 3;
```

Furthermore, I think that you can simplify the `findUnassignedLocation` function :

```
function findUnassignedLocation(grid, row, col) {
    for (; row < 9 ; col = 0, row++)
        for (; col < 9 ; col++)
            if (grid[row][col] == 0)
                return [row, col];
    return [-1, -1];
}
```